# How can I position an icon next to a label in a crispy modelform?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a modelform and append a font awesome icon next to the first_name field:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['first_name',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            AppendedText('first name', mark_safe('<span class="fas fa-user"></span>')),
        }
```

How can I appen an icon to the fields label? I want to append a help icon which the user can click on to get hints on the field.